# @ContextConfiguration and Security Chain Filter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, integration-testing

I'm trying to implement integration testing in my app and have test class like that:

```
@ExtendWith(value={SpringExtension.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes={AppConfiguration.class,WebMvcConfiguration.class})
public class TestClass{ ... }
```

inside class i have:

```
mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity()).build();
```

Sadly `@Autowired` cannot find my Security Spring Chain Filter (or `DelegatingFilterProxy`) and without it I feel like I won't be able to achievie full functionality of integration testing in spring (espescially the spring-security-test part).  In my opinion it's because I initialize my whole app by creating a class that extends `AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer`. I also feel like adding some sort of custom initializer or loader classes into `@ContextConfiguration` would help, but acutally have no idea how to do it. Do you guys think it will help and/or can you guys steer me into creating my own loader/initializer?

Comment: The filter isn't part of the context, but still registered due to the manual registration of the `SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity()`. Security should just work with that.

Comment: I saw on some code samples that people inject filters chain and pass it as parameter to this method. What is the diffrence between `SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity()` and passing it as param?

Comment: Because you are mocking the setup with this instead of letting your regular configuration do it.

Comment: So basically what you are saying is that everything is mocked, and I'm fine with that. sadly I'm missing something. When i want to perform `  mvc.perform(get("/user/my_details").with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user(user))).andDo(print())` as a response I get redirection to homepage. object user result of the `userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(myLogin);` which is the same the same class that is in security spring config. What am I doing wrong?